# How to configure localhost on android mobile and access it in offline?

Tags: android

Hello guys I just want to ask how can I enable access to localhost even without internet connection(wifi). Because I installed an android application which is Servers Ultimate and AndroPHP. If the Internet is enabled, I can access to the localhost using 127.0.0.1:8080 but if the Internet is disabled I can't access the localhost. I also checked the settings and there is nothing that I can found.

Answer (score 2):

Can you access `http://localhost` firstly?
Secondly, can you login to phpmyadmin using just AndroPHP?

Comment: If my Internet is enabled I can access the localhost. And I can also login to phpmyadmin.

Comment: If the Internet is not enabled? As for the second part of your reply, can it be done offline?

Comment: No, I can't access my localhost if the Internet is not enabled.

Comment: I got something I need to confirm. Try turning on the WiFi on the phone, but do not connect to any network. After that, go to localhost again. Based on the outcome, I may be able to help further.

Comment: what do you mean any network? mobile network? or wifi network? I tried turning on my wifi and i didn't connect to any network but same effect.

Comment: I indeed meant WiFi network. So I see that it just will not allow you to access localhost without an Internet connection. I think I know the reason.

It does not allow you to connect because the server service is not directly on your phone. Therefore, you need the connection to connect to the service.